# unable to install robotframework-ride

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

i am trying to install robotframework-ride but installation getting failed.i tried all possible option but failed to resolve the issue.same issue in both windows and ubuntu 18 and 20

```
python3 -m pip install robotframework-ride

Error running configure
  ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "build.py", line 1510, in cmd_build_wx
      wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-_os0c4ab/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 373, in main
      "Error running configure")
    File "/tmp/pip-build-_os0c4ab/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
      raise builder.BuildError(msg)
  buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error running configure
  Finished command: build_wx (0m2.579s)
  Finished command: build (0m2.579s)
  Command '"/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for wxPython

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_os0c4ab/wxPython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xws6qhs5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_os0c4ab/wxPython/
```

Answer (score 0):

To install RIDE on Ubuntu 20.04 do this

```
sudo apt update
sudo install python3-wxgtk4.0
pip install robotframework-ride
```

To execute Ride run

```
ride.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [Release Notes of RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/releases), to know about the dependency on wxPython.

On Windows and Mac there is no problem, but on Linux you should install it first from the correct .wheel file (wxpython.org).

The version you are trying to install is 1.7.4.2 and it requires version 4.0.7.post2 of wxPython.

Probably you need to install `wheel`:

```
pip install wheel
```